# Hexadecimal Value In C++ Switch Statement

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

Is it possible to perform a switch with a hexadecimal case statement?

for example:

```
switch (integer) {
    case: 1
         function();
         break;
    case: F:
         function();
         break;
}
```

g++ complains saying:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:148:18: error: ‘F’ was not declared in this scope
```

I assume the compiler is  trying to treat `F` as a variable. I know instead of `F` I could just use the value `15` but hex would be more convenient.

Solutions for other control statements would be nice too.

Comment: google "c++ hex literal"

Comment: much better. Thanks guys. @PlasmaHH I tried to google it but forgot to use the word literal so didn't get relevant results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C, and presumably C++ as well, you can use any integer constant in a switch statement. That's not your problem.

Your problem is that `F` isn't a constant, it's a variable name. To specify your constant in hex, use a leading `0x`, e.g. `0xf`.

The same thing applies in any other context that can take a (decimal) value - you get hex by using a leading `0x`. Or if you want octal for some reason, use a leading `0`, without the x.

Thus `017`, `0xf` and `15` are all the same number, and can be used interchangeably in c.

Comment: *Thus `017`, `0xf` and `15` are all the same number, and can be used interchangeably in c.* That's true for this particular value, but not for `2147483648` and `0x80000000` on systems with 32-bit ints: `2147483648 == 0x80000000` and `-1 < 2147483648` are true but `-1 < 0x80000000` is false.

Answer (score 11):

123 is treated as decimal.
0123 is treated as octal.
0x123 is treated as hexadecimal.
0b101 is treated as binary (C++14).

You need to use 0xF.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to assign a hex value to a variable you have to use a prefix `0x`, in your case `int var = 0xF`

Answer (score 1):

Yes; prefix the hex values with `0x` to have the compiler treat them as hex literals.
Similarly, prefix with `0` to have them be treated as octal.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is.  use this syntax:

```
unsigned char buffer[12];
switch (buffer[0]) {
     case 0x01:
          // your code
          break;
     case 0xAA:
          // your code
          break;
}
```